# Binding a key sequence to a key sequence instead of a command

Tags: key-bindings, commands, keyboard-macros

In my .emacs, I tried to use

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-r") (kbd "C-x r j")`

so I can use `M-r` to jump to a register. However, doing this and using the command gives

`After 0 kbd macro iterations: Args out of range: [], 0`

as an error in the minibuffer. Looking up the shortcut with `C-h k` shows that the keyboard shortcut is bound to `jump-to-register`. Then, using

`(global-set-key (kbd "M-r") 'jump-to-register)`

gets the desired behavior, and my shortcut works.

*My question is:* why doesn't my first attempt work, esp. if it just really seems to be calling the same function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this in Emacs 25.2.2. The problem is that when `jump-to-register` attempts to read the character that identifies the register, Emacs still thinks it's running a macro, but it has no more characters available. Your approach would work with a function that doesn't attempt to read extra input.

At the Lisp level, `jump-to-register` calls `read-key` which calls `read-key-sequence-vector`. In this scenario, `read-key-sequence-vector` returns an empty vector. `read-key` does not expect this and throws the error you saw. This looks like a bug in `read-key-sequence-vector` since it isn't documented as ever reading an empty vector and I don't see why it would.

Comment: Thanks Gilles! Maybe I should submit a bug request.